# Get ARN of S3 Bucket with aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Is it possible to get the ARN of an S3 bucket via the AWS command line?

I have looked through the documentation for `aws s3api ...` and `aws s3 ...` and have not found a way to do this.

Comment: Can't believe this is real. For years now there is no way to get a definite ARN from CLI.

Comment: Amazon Web Services hates its users

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html

Answer (score 174, accepted):

It's always `arn:PARTITION:s3:::NAME-OF-YOUR-BUCKET`. If you know the name of the bucket and in which partition it's located, you know the ARN. No need to 'get' it from anywhere.

The PARTITION will be `aws`, `aws-us-gov`, or `aws-cn`depending on whether you're in general AWS, GovCloud, or China resepectively.

Comment: Probably why your AWS S3 bucket names have to be globally unique; but it's a horrid wart to couple these together that way.  The interpolation of an account ID into that ARN would be much better. :(

Comment: Was hoping for a way to do this without making any assumptions about the ARN format.  Buckets in cn-north-1 region are arn:aws-cn:s3:::BUCKET_NAME and I was hoping to avoid having to "know" how Amazon assigned ARNs in case Amazon were to change the rules.

Comment: @ljcundiff an ARN is a non-opaque, constructible identifier, apparently by design.  They aren't at all likely to change the [documented rules for the S3 ARN format](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/s3-arn-format.html).  The `cn-north-1` region is special case, as is GovCloud, because those are completely cordoned off from the global `aws` partition, not accessible with the same sets of keys.  If you're working in multiple partitions, you have to know which partition you're dealing with.

Comment: usually have to add `BUCKET_NAME/*` the "/*" at the end AFAIK

Comment: Some S3 apis do not support this ARN, eg: `aws s3api get-bucket-acl --bucket arn:aws:s3:::mybucket` will return bucket name error complaining it does not match one of the regular expressions: `<...> or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:s3:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"`

Answer (score 18):

You can also select your S3 bucket ARN by selecting it using the tick mark at the s3 management console, which will pop up a Side bar. where there is a provision to copy your S3 bucket ARN.[S3 management console with bucket ARN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP1ex.jpg)

Answer (score 5):

aws articles spell out the arn format but never say go here to see it. Highlighting my s3 bucket and seeing that **Copy Bucket ARN** kept me sane for a few more hours.

Comment: Your answer is more helpful than the aws docs on this topic, which talk endlessly *about* a bucket ARN, but don't actually tell you where to go if you simply want to copy it