# Get ARN of S3 **COMPATIBLE** bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, dreamhost, linode

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253054/get-arn-of-s3-bucket-with-aws-cli/41253103) asked similarly how to get the ARN of an AWS S3 Bucket from the CLI. However the selected answer just states something like *it is what it is, blah blah blah*.  Essentially the S3 ARN is a string with a very specific format, for example: `arn:aws:s3:::MyBucket`.

But what about S3 *compatible* services like *Linode / Dreamhost / HostEurope / Dunkel Storage / Wasabi*, I can't find any reference other than the official ARN syntax [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) with any relation to 3rd party services so I can only guess. The specific component I'm confused about is the **partition** (the 2nd part). For instance is it `arn:linode:s3:::mybucket`?

Does anyone have either a way to list the ARN of a resource using the AWS CLI (or any other compatible CLI for that matter), or any reference to syntax for 3rd party ARN's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the horses mouth... Linode support (who are as an aside the best customer support team I've ever worked with) was able to clear this up for me, at least for their service. The correct ARN for the Linode S3 *Compatible* service is...

```
arn:linode:s3:::mybucket
```

Hope that saves you a little time.